# What is the returned value of this fetchImage() function?

Tags: javascript

```
async function fetchImage(url) {
    const img = new Image();
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        img.onload = () => res(img);
        img.onerror = e => rej(e);
        img.src = url;
    });
}
const img = await fetchImage('https://covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/12547191-L.jpg');
const w = img.width;
const h = img.height;
```

Given this piece of code I found on the Open Library Covers API, could anyone clarify what exactly does the fetchImage() function return? And what would be the variable type of the img constant outside of the fetchImage function?

In my mind, it seems as if the fetchImage function returns a Promise Object, but if this piece of code is supposed to be correct, it will return an Image object. Could anyone clarify this?

Tried asking ChatGPT but it just kept giving me contradicting answers (powers of the AI).

Comment: no, it return an image element (`<img...>`), if the promise is done without error, otherwise it retrun an "error element"

Comment: `but if this piece of code is supposed to be correct` no, this piece of code is erroneous

Comment: "*it seems as if the `fetchImage` function returns a Promise Object*" - yes it does. And then you `await` it, getting the `Image` that the promise is fulfilled with.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct: `fetchImage()` returns a Promise.
But later on in you're code you are using `await` which "waits" for the Promise to resolve.

You can read more on async functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

In your example

```
console.log(fetchImage(imgPath))
```

Will print out
[object Promise]

And

```
console.log(await fetchImage(imgPath))
```

Will print out the result, given that you won't get an error while trying to resolve the promise.

Comment: could you explain what does the const img = await fetchImage does? wouldnt const img be set to the return value of fetchimage()?

Comment: Await does exactly that - it waits for the promise to resolve and assigns the result to the `img`. 
More formally: "The await operator is used to wait for a Promise and get its fulfillment value."